# Facebook Audience Network SDK for iOS is not logging impressions

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-audience-network

We have integrated the Audience Network Facebook SDK to our iOS app. When testing locally, the app does log impressions and ads are requested/filled. When the app was released to production, impressions stopped logging. Our fill rate is very high, as well as our clicks but the dashboard is showing 0 impressions. Using our own analytic tools, we are 100% sure that users are receiving and viewing ads. What might be the problem here?

Comment: I also face this problem. Did you solved this issue?

Comment: Yes it actually turned out to be a temporary bug with their reporting dashboard. As Facebook does not have any customer support tools - the best thing to do is to make a post here: 
https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ and to open a support ticket with the Audience Network. Our impressions appeared a few days later.

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: It was fixed the next day, however it might have occurred again